# Why is req.query always empty?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I'm trying to make a POST request to Express, but whenever I do, I can't access req.query. It's always empty.

The POST request works in Postman, but I can't get it to work in React.

I am wondering if whatever axios is sending over is not readable by the Express middleware. **I'm new to Express, so I'm sure I'm missing something basic.** Thanks for reading!

**From my React file:**

```
tryPost = () => {
  axios.post('/login', {
    firstName: 'Tom',
    lastName: 'Rains'
  });
}
```

**From my Express file:**

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log('test'); //prints test
  console.log(req.query); //prints as {}
})
```

Comment: See what is in your post body. In my opinion, the query should be something like this “login/?firstName=Tom&lastName=Rains”, maybe you’ve put your “query” in the post body.  Please try req.body to see what’s there.  :)

Comment: @Neal.Marlin the answer would be nothing unless the right body parsing middleware is also setup :)

Comment: @James Yeah, you’re right. I just supposed the right thing had been done. :) Because we’re not talking about how to configure the express middleware

Comment: Hi guys, you were right, I didn't have the right body parsing middleware. Thanks for the comments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[req.query](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) refers to *query string* parameters, in your example you POST a JSON formatted *body*, no query string parameters are sent hence `req.query` is empty.

Depending on what way you intend to POST the data, if you want to pass it as query string data then you need to do:

```
axios.post('/login?firstName=Tom&lastName=Rains');
```

And then your code would work as is. However, If you want to POST the data as a body (like your example), then there is an additional change that needs applied in your express app i.e.

```
app.use(express.json())
```

This will ensure the JSON body gets parsed, then you can access the data via `req.body` from your route.

Note - Make sure this is configured *before* you setup your routes

Comment: Thank you!! I just added in app.use(express.json()) to my Express and it's working now! This answer was super clear and helped me understand the difference betweeen req.body and req.query. Now time for me to dive into this MERN app! :D